# Postman returns 204 no content error to post request

Tags: asp.net, post, postman

My request's body:
{
    "author":"Dan Brown",
    "title":"Da Vinci's code"
}.
And I am sending request to http://localhost:49497/api/values.
It is returning 204 error.What can be the reason of this problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace APIlab2.Controllers
{
    public class TestObject
    {
        public string author{ get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        List<TestObject> list = new List<TestObject>();
        public IEnumerable<TestObject> Get()
        {
            return list;
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody]TestObject obj)
        {
            list.Add(obj);
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

204 is not an error. You are not returning anything from the server. Just adding it to the list. Hence  no content is returned

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Postman.

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2418